# Trouble creating ODBC Driver for oracle installed on a remote server

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I am trying to implement a vlookup functionality from my excel sheet to an oracle (11G) database.

I was able to establish a connection to the database using the below connection string, but I am able to only download a copy of the table.

(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid)))

I was looking at this post which suggests to create a ODBC data source to perform a vlookup.

[Excel vlookup incorporating SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977348/excel-vlookup-incorporating-sql-table)

Can someone please let me know if I can create an ODBC data source to an oracle instance on a remote machine, if so what is the connection string format that I should be using as the below format doesnt seem to work.

(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid)))

Thanks

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use? Microsoft or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect using this connection string.

host:port/servicename

Thank you.