# SQL operand data type datetime / varchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum, intervals

I am trying to subtract one column from another column, and then sum the result. However, whatever I change I keep getting one of the two errors as mentioned in the title.

From all other questions posted, I derived that my statement should be something like:

```
SELECT SUM(EndTime-BeginTime) AS TotalTime FROM TimeRegister 
WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
```

As per suggestion in another topic, I changed the statement to:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(varchar(EndTime-BeginTime), 108)) AS TotalTime FROM TimeRegister 
WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
```

However, I still receive the error.
The times are stored as follows:

```
1-1-1900 7:30:00
```

Thanks for any suggestion...

---

**Edit 1:** Oh, I am using a Microsoft Query through ODBC for SQL in Excel, kind of like:
[Excel vlookup incorporating SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977348/excel-vlookup-incorporating-sql-table)

---

**Edit 2:** I prefer to have the output again in the HH:MM format.

The thing is, when I copy the complete database to excel, everything works just fine. I can subtract the columns and sum up. I just dont want to that manually every day....

---

I just checked the SQL database, and the column is of Date/Time type.

Comment: If the columns are of a date datatype (as they should), you can use `DATEDIFF()`

Comment: The problem is that you converted the date to text in the first place. Whatever that other topic was, it was wrong if it suggested that converting dates to text would solve anything. What output do you expect to get? Minutes? Seconds? A `time` value ?

Comment: BTW `1-1-1900 7:30:00` isn't a `time` value and one can only guess what the actual type is. Maybe it's datetime, maybe it's smalldatetime.

Comment: try converting in datetime every column before making a SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,__converted_EndTime,__converted_BeginTime))

Comment: @SnakeFoot you assume the OP wants minutes. Which is probably a good guess.

Comment: The first query is valid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language - every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the problem is the result, not whether this is valid or not. AFAIK only Postgresql has an interval type, so it's not PostgreSql. I'd bet (99.9999%) this is SQL Server where subtracting two dates returns another date.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Oracle also has an interval  data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. That `CONVERT` though is T-SQL

Comment: Thanks everyone. It seems that Snakefoot is very close with the answer. SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,EndTime,BeginTime)) Does work in the end with the original columns. Which yields an integer number: 34950. I checked and it was indeed 34950 minutes. So, Thanks for that, but I cant select your comment as solution...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, trying to solve date or numeric issues by converting to text never solves anything, it adds additional problems like failed conversions or unexpected results.

SQL Server doesn't have a time interval type. If you subtract two `datetime` values you get back another `datetime` value that represents the difference as the offset since 1900-01-01. The following query :

```
select getdate() - dateadd(d,-1,getdate())
```

Will return :

```
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Which *is* 1 full day after 1900-01-01.

`datetime` values can't be summed though. SQL Server *does* have a `time` type but that just represents the time of day. Even if `today - yesterday` worked, converting that to `time` would return `00:00`.

A quick solution is to use `DATEDIFF` to calculate the difference between two dates in whatever unit is required - hourss, minutes, seconds etc. Be aware though that `DATEDIFF` returns the number of interval boundaries crossed. `DATEDIFF(DAY,...)` between 11pm yesterday and 1am today will return *1*, because 1 day boundary was crossed.

You can use

```
SELECT sum(datediff(minute,EndTime,BeginTime)) AS TotalMinutes
FROM TimeRegister 
WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
```

To calculate the difference in minutes and format it as a time interval on the client.

Another option is to cast the `datetime` to a `float` before summing, then back to datetime:

```
SELECT cast( sum(cast(EndTime - BeginTime as datetime)) as datetime) AS TotalOffset
FROM TimeRegister 
WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
```

A 2-day duration would appear as :

```
1900-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

This works because `datetime` can be cast to a float whose integral part represents the offset from 1900-01-01 and the fractional part the time.

A client written in a language like C# that *does* support intervals could subtract `1900-01-01` from this to get back the actual duration, eg :

```
TimeSpan duration = sumResult - new DateTime(1900,1,1);
```

Another option would be to avoid the final cast and just use the resulting `float` value as the number of days.

**Displaying in Excel**

The last option could be the easiest way to display the duration in Excel! Excel dates are actually stored as floats. What makes them appear as dates or times is the cell's formatting.

You can set a cells format to `[h]:mm:ss` to display any number as a duration. The `[]` is important - without it Excel will only display the time part of the "date".

If you enter `2` in a cell, `h:mm:ss` will show it as `0:00:00` while `[h]:mm:ss` will display `48:00:00`, 48 hours.

Despite its strangeness,

```
SELECT sum(cast(EndTime - BeginTime as datetime)) AS TotalDuration
FROM TimeRegister 
WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
```

May be the best option to display a duration sum in Excel

Comment: Pretty thorough answer, +1. Maybe a word of warning that subtraction will not work on `datetime2` data will perhaps make it even more complete.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
WITH totalTime AS (
  SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(second,  EndTime, BeginTime)) as TimeInSecond
  FROM TimeRegister 
  WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
)
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(TimeinSecond / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST((TimeinSecond / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(TimeinSecond % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) AS TimeElapsed
FROM totalTime;
```

In this solution, the time is converted into seconds, before being totalled, and then converted to HH:MM:SS.

Comment: This won't work and doesn't do what the OP asked for anyway - aggregating time.  Converting to text is what *caused* the problem in the first place.

Comment: I suspect it's what the OP is trying to do, "As per suggestion in another topic". While I'm not addressing the error mentioned, I believe it is a solution to the problem.

Comment: When I use the statement then I get a column in return, which is, partly, as I want. Now I would want to sum up that column, and then I get the error again...

Comment: @RobertHaa converting to text is the bug. You can't solve it with additional text manipulation, that's what *caused* the problem. Explain what you want instead - aggregate durations. Provide the actual field types.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni it doesn't solve the problem, it adds another problem on top. It won't return correct data either - try it with times 1 day apart. The result is 00:00.

Comment: @RobertHaa OK, I think I was getting confused by the OP and the attempts to fix it. I have amended my proposed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `datediff()`:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(second, BeginTime, EndTime) AS TotalTime
FROM TimeRegister 
WHERE OrderNumber = 00000 AND Activity = 11111;
```